# Cant deploy Elastic on Kubernetes on Azure as azure-cli wheezy InRelease is not signed in the repo

Tags: azure, azure-aks

The deployment fails when the controllervm wants to install the azure-cli package:

> The following additional packages will be installed:n aufs-tools
>   cgroupfs-mount libapr1 libaprutil1 libltdl7 openresty-openssln
>   openresty-opm openresty-pcre openresty-resty openresty-zlib
>   pigznSuggested packages:n mountall openresty-restydoc zipn. The
>   following NEW packages will be installed:n apache2-utils aufs-tools
>   azure-cli cgroupfs-mount docker-ce libapr1n libaprutil1 libltdl7
>   openresty openresty-openssl openresty-opmn openresty-pcre
>   openresty-resty openresty-zlib pigz unzipn0 upgraded, 16 newly
>   installed, 0 to remove and 86 not upgraded. Need to get 111 MB/111 MB
>   of archives.nAfter this operation, 486 MB of additional disk space
>   will be used.nWARNING: The following packages cannot be
>   authenticated!n azure-clinn[stderr]ngpg: requesting key 417A0893 from
>   hkp server packages.microsoft.comngpg: key 417A0893: public key "MS
>   Open Tech interop@microsoft.com" importedngpg: Total number processed:
>   1ngpg: imported: 1 (RSA: 1)nW: GPG error:
>   **https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli wheezy InRelease: The
>   following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is
>   not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CFnW: The repository
>   'https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli wheezy InRelease' is
>   not signed.**

I can ssh into the vm and correct the error to install the packages afterwards but I cannot manually continue the full deployment.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Microsoft/elk-acs-kubernetes/issues/58

It was a known issue as they responded on github. In the meantime I manually continued the install after adding the right GPG public key to the apt client.